# Tricky Differential Equations Questions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am self studying differential equations, and ran into some problems I have never seen before.

The majority of problems I have solved have come int the form of $Ay''-by'+C = 0$. I clearly understand how to solve these, and arrive at the general solutions.

However, I am now encountering a problem like 
$2t^2y''-5ty'+6y = 0$ where they give a solution $y(t) = t^\frac32)$.

Does this now mean I have to work backwards from before since we already have a solution given to us?

Likewise, how does the general form look different in the case when
$2t^2y'' - 5ty' + 6t = t^2 - 1$. I know this revolves around methods of undetermined coefficients, and have guessed $Ax^2+Bx+C$ and have differentiating it twice over for y'' and once over for y', but I still haven't organized my work together to arrive at a general solution.

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The differential equation
$$2t^2y''-5ty'+6y = 0$$
or
$$4t^2y''-10ty'+12y = 0$$
known as [Euler differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html), which can be solved with substitution $x=\ln2t$. In this case when the right side is zero, the differential equation 
$$(at)^2y''+paty'+qy = 0$$
is homogeneous and with $x=\ln at$ is converted to
$$y''+\left(\dfrac{p}{a}-1\right)y'+\dfrac{p}{a^2}y = 0$$
then with characteristic equation
$$\lambda^2+\left(\dfrac{p}{a}-1\right)\lambda+\dfrac{p}{a^2}=0$$
we may find it's general solution.

---

**Edit:**
After substitution $x=\ln 2t$, your equation is
$$y''-\dfrac72y'+3y=2e^{2x}-2\tag{*}$$
from characteristic equation, the general solution is
$$y_g=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{\frac32x}$$
and while the right side of equation (*) has item $e^{2x}$ which is one of the general solutions, then let $y=Axe^{2x}+B$ to find particular solution with [undetermined coefficient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients). After $A$ and $B$ were found, put $x=\ln 2t$ and return main independent variable. One may find further examples [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulerEquations.aspx).

Comment: I have researched online for my question to Part A, and it suggests that I can use the Wronskian to derive another fundamental solution, which I can work backwards to find another fundamental solution and attain the general solution? Would that method work.

Also, is my guess correct regarding my second equation?

Comment: I've added some details. Can you proceed?

Comment: If you have a solution, you can fin the second with $$y_2=y_1\int\frac{e^{-\int p\,dx}}{y_1^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for all this information. Where does the condition that y = t^3/2 come into play in this problem

Comment: You are welcome and try more with examples, you will find the problem easy!

Comment: Just one last clarification however, how does giving y(t) = t^3/2 as a solution come into play in the problem?...

Edit: 
I see you have already solved the general solution. Hence, the provided initial solution can be used as a sort of double check to your answer. Thanks

Comment: So to summarize everything:'

The solution to part A is attained through Euler's method. I can do the computations but we arrive at the general solution you provided with 2 and the given 3/2

The solution to part B just requires simple usage of undetermined coefficients? 

Thank you for your help

Comment: Write. So in part B, I already have the general solution.
Now I want particular solution. To solve for particular pollution, we need to guess the undetermined coefficients. If the RHS is t^2-1, why can't we just guess At^2 + Bt + C? Why are you guessing y=Axe^2x+B

Thank you.

Comment: I utilized the examples that you showed me in link. I simply converted the equation to 2r(r-1)-5r+6...and got the same general solution as well. With the first solution being 2, and the second 3/2 after quadratic formula.

Is it necessary to take x = ln2t? Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: yes it's necessary, the solution $y_g=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{\frac32x}$ is after substitution, and the main general solution is $$y_g=C_1e^{2\ln2t}+C_2e^{\frac32\ln2t}$$

Comment: I guess I am just a bit confused because the examples in the link you give me did not use (ln) for any of their solutions, even the final general solutions. I simply have c1t^2 + c2t^3/2. Would that be wrong?

Comment: c1t^2 + c2t^3/2 is right. in deed $$y_g=C_1e^{2\ln2t}+C_2e^{\frac32\ln2t}=C_1t^2+C'_2t^\frac32$$

Comment: Then if I directly guess Ax^2 + Bx +C instead of your guess, will I get the same solution in part B if I were to use your guess. 

I have got the same solution as you without using ln2t.

Comment: Of course. two ways are the same. what's your final solution?

Comment: using Ax^2 + Bx + C 

I got A = 1/10...B = -1/6 ...and C = -1/36.

Comment: I really don't know whether method of undetermined coefficients works when we have $2t^2y''+\cdots$ or not. I think it works for equation of the form $y''+...$..

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's informative to look at degrees, considering $t$ as raising the degree with one and $\frac{d}{dt}$ as lowering the degree with one. For all the terms in your differential equation you have as many $t$ factors as applications of $\frac{d}{dt}$ and the degree therefore remains unchanged. Even more important is that the degree changes in the same way for every term. This means that if the solution in some way can be written as a sum $y(t) = \sum_{\alpha \in A} c_\alpha t^\alpha$ then the differential equation works on each term separately. In this case you get $2t^2 y'' - 5ty' + 6y = \sum_{\alpha \in A} (2\alpha(\alpha-1)-5\alpha+6) c_\alpha t^\alpha.$ so for the differential equation to be satisfied you must have $(2\alpha(\alpha-1)-5\alpha+6) c_\alpha = 0,$ i.e. $2(\alpha-2)(\alpha-\frac32)c_\alpha=0.$ Thus $c_\alpha$ can only be nonzero for $\alpha=2$ and $\alpha=\frac32.$

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative route, but I think it is better to follow the answer by user 108128.  Rewrite the differential equation as
$$y''(t)-\frac{5}{2t}\,y'(t)+\frac{3}{t^2}\,y(t)=f(t)\,,$$
where $f$ is a source function.  (Note that $f\equiv 0$ in the homogeneous case, and $$f(t)=\frac{t^2-1}{2t^2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)$$ for the nonhomogeneous equation in question.)  Observe that $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\left(y'(t)-\frac{2}{t}\,y(t)\right)-\frac{1}{2t}\,\left(y'(t)-\frac{2}{t}\,y(t)\right)=f(t)\,.$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,\left(y'(t)-\frac{2}{t}\,y(t)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,f(t)\,.$$
Ergo,
$$y'(t)-\frac{2}{t}\,y(t)=\sqrt{t}\,F(t)\,,$$
where $\displaystyle F(t):=\int\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t$.  Finally, we write
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\,y(t)\right)=t^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,F(t)\,,$$
so that
$$y(t)=t^2\,\int\,t^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,F(t)\,\text{d}t\,.$$

> To solve the homogeneous solution (i.e., with $f\equiv 0$, we have $F(t)=-\frac{1}{2}\,A$ for some constant $A$.  That is, $$y(t)=t^2\,\int\,\left(-\frac{1}{2}\,A\right)\,t^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,\text{d}t=t^2\,\left(A\,t^{-\frac{1}{2}}+B\right)=A\,t^{\frac{3}{2}}+B\,t^2\,,$$ for some constant $B$. 
>  For the nonhomogeneous solution with $f(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\,\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)$, we get $$F(t)=\int\,\frac{1}{2}\left(t^{-\frac{1}{2}}-t^{-\frac{5}{2}}\right)\,\text{d}t=t^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{3}\,t^{-\frac{3}{2}}-\frac12\,a\,,$$ where $a$ is a constant.  That is,  $$y(t)=t^2\,\int\,t^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,\left(t^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{3}\,t^{-\frac{3}{2}}-\frac12\,a\right)\,\text{d}t=t^2\,\left(\ln(t)-\frac{1}{6}t^{-2}+a\,t^{-\frac{1}{2}}+b\right)\,,$$ for some constant $b$.  Thus,  $$y(t)=t^2\,\ln(t)-\frac{1}{6}+a\,t^{\frac{3}{2}}+b\,t^2\,.$$

---

**P.S.**  You can also rewrite the differential equation as
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\left(y'(t)-\frac{3}{2t}\,y(t)\right)-\frac{1}{t}\,\left(y'(t)-\frac{3}{2t}\,y(t)\right)=f(t)\,.$$
This leads to 
$$y(t)=t^{\frac32}\,\int\,t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,\tilde{F}(t)\,\text{d}t\,,$$
where $$\tilde{F}(t):=\int\,\frac{1}{t}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t\,.$$

Comment: I used Ax^2 + Bx+ C for my guess for the nonhomogenous equation. I attained  A = 1/10...B = -1/6 ...and C = -1/36....

Why does my solution vary drastically from yours

Comment: That doesn't work.  If you plug in $y(t)=At^2+Bt+C$ into the nonhomogeneous equation, you will get $$Bt+6C=t^2-1\,.$$  But a linear polynomial is never equal to a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: hmmm but I always assumed you make your guess based on the right side. You at least, and at most, want to match the highest polynomial. Why doesn't a standard polynomial guess not work?

Comment: say for example I have the equation y''-2y+2y = 2e^t. I would base my guess on the RHS. So wouldn't my guess just simply be Ae^t for this particular question?

Comment: It is actually the other way around.  If a guess works, then it is mostly a miracle (usually because the problem is designed to allow certain forms of educated guesses).  But if a random problem is thrown at you, chances are that none of your known elementary functions will work.  There is no particular reason why certain guesses work, why some do not.

Comment: I guess these problems are relatively basic enough for some formulaic conclusions to be made in attaining the guess. Then what particular characteristics of the function should I be watching out for to make a more educated guess.  y''-2y+2y = 2e^t -> Wouldn't Ae^t simply be enough?

Comment: Your "guess" $y(t)=A\exp(t)$ for $y''(t)-2y'(t)+2y(t)=2\exp(t)$ comes from the fact that somebody told you it should work.  This is very far away from being a guess.  For simple ODEs like this, we have proven what particular solutions look like.  You were taught that it is just a guess, but it is actually not.  It is much more than an educated guess.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I guess to be direct, Ae2^t is the accurate approach for that particular question. But if Ae2^t is the accurate approach to THAT problem, why doesn't At^2 + B^t + C work for the particular problem in question. I don't recall integrals being used in finding general solutions for non-homogenous equations.

Comment: The question "why don't quadratics work here" does not make sense.  You can prove that they don't work.  There are no reasons why they should work, or why they shouldn't work, until you plug them in to see whether they work.  There are no particular reason why $y(t)=t^2\,\ln(t)-\frac{1}{6}$ works either. It's just that this one works.

Comment: And you are very wrong to think that solving a differential equation does not involve integrals.

Comment: Can you clarify what your guess is to the non-homogenous equation is?  I think your response may be a little too complicated for my level

I understand what your saying. Thank you for your elegant response and for helping me.

Comment: I did not guess.  I found it through algebraic manipulations, and then solved the differential equations involved.

Comment: Is it possible for you to do it through the "guess" approach. I haven't been taught to solve non-homogenous equations without  formulaic guessing. I think your approach is advanced for my level, but I'm eager to learn it. But based on my current standing, do you know what a good "guess" to the non-homogenous equation is. This is what I/my teacher uses to guide us......... https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=undetermined+coefficients&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwnsy0vdXcAhWDTn0KHWMTAZUQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=703#imgrc=8wLwNViwdDEutM:

Comment: I would not know to guess $t^2\,\ln(t)-\frac16$, and don't really like to guess. However, if you know the homogeneous solutions, you can find a particular solution by using the Wronskian technique.  See for example here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx.  Nonetheless, it is not a very easy to find the homogeneous solutions either.  You may need to make educated guesses (real guesses) or manage some very clever algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Wow great source. Thanks a ton Mr. Batominovski! I will check if this method will arrive at the same solution you have provided